# Cartthrob report templates: using overall order data while in order items loop

Tags: cartthrob, tags

I'm trying to create a custom report.  In it, I need a table with rows that would look like this:

```
 # Product   Order id Order date
 1 Partridge 1234567  2014-09-15
 2 Dove      1234567  2014-09-15
12 Drummer   1234567  2014-09-15
 3 Dove      2345678  2014-08-01
 4 Drummer   2345678  2014-08-01
```

Clearly this involves a loop over orders, and an inner loop over the items in the order.  However, I haven't been able to access much of the order's data from within the item's loop. While i can see the order ID, I can't seem to access the date the order was entered; instead, `entry_date` gives *the product's creation date*, which is not what I want at all.  Other attempts -- starting a second-level `exp:channel:entries` loop with the appropriate order ID, guessing at possible prefixes or containers for order data (like `entry:entry_date` or `order:entry_date`) haven't gotten me anywhere.  The following is the code I've written for this so far.

```
<table>
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders"}
    {order_items variable_prefix="item_"}
        <tr>
            <td>{item:quantity}</td>
            <td>{item:title}</td>
            <td>{order_id}</td>
            <td>{entry_date}</td>
        </tr>
    {/order_items}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got an email from cartthrob support; they offered a solution: embeds.  All the following code is from them.

In reports/.order_date I put:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="1"}
{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

THen I changed the relevant line in my report to say

```
{embed="reports/.order_date" entry_id="{order_id}"}
```

Inside the embed, the loops and other data from the main template don't exist; all I can see are the globals (like `exp`) and the parameters I pass in (`order_id`).  Thus, using a quasi-loop within won't break anything, and I don't have to worry about anything shadowing my variables.

Comment: Hi thanks for the nice post, I will apply these tips